# SQL get current date with specific time

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get orders which are approved between 8AM and 4PM

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    orders 
WHERE 
    approved_date BETWEEN 'CURDATE() 8:00:00' AND 'CURDATE() 16:00:00'
```

Here I am trying to get orders which are approved after 4PM  (till next working day 8AM)

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    orders 
WHERE 
    approved_date BETWEEN 'CURDATE() 16:00:00' AND 'NEXT_WORKING_DAY 8:00:00'
```

How to write these queries correctly?

*approved_date* is **DATETIME** format (0000-00-00 00:00:00)
using MySQL

Edit: working day = monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday

Answer (score 1):

Use [timestampadd](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd)

```
timestampadd(HOUR, 16, CURDATE()) # 4 pm
timestampadd(HOUR, 32, CURDATE()) # 8 am the next day
```

Comment: @Ravinder - sure - the original example was just showing the idea - not the specific example,

Answer (score 1):

Use it as this:

```
timestampadd(HOUR, 16, CURDATE()) # same day 16:00

timestampadd(HOUR, 32, CURDATE()) # next day 8:00
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
 WHERE date(approved_date) = CURDATE() AND
       time(approved_date) BETWEEN '8:00:00' AND '16:00:00'
```

I don't understand what the "NEXT_WORKING_DAY" is supposed to mean.  Perhaps it is this:

```
WHERE date(approved_date) = CURDATE() AND time(approved_date) >= '8:00:00' OR
      date(approved_date = CURDATE() + 1 AND time(approved_date) <= '16:00:00'
```

Comment: working day = business day (e.g. if Friday, next working day is Monday )